# Azure Active Directory Sign out Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory

I've created a generic website from visual studio 2013 and successfully wired it up to an existing Azure Active Directory instance for authentication. I can login as any user in the Azure AD with the appropriate credentials. Unfortunately I can not sign out without receiving this error:

> AADSTS50068: Signout failed. The initiating application is not a
>   participant in the current session.

I've googled the error number, but apparently I'm the first person to ever encounter this....:) I'm pretty sure I'm not, but I'm now at a loss to explain why sign in works, but sign out does not.

Here is the sign out code, pretty much exactly as it was generated:

```
public ActionResult SignOut()
        {
            WsFederationConfiguration config = FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfiguration.WsFederationConfiguration;

            // Redirect to SignOutCallback after signing out.
            string callbackUrl = Url.Action("SignOutCallback", "Account", routeValues: null, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);

            SignOutRequestMessage signoutMessage = new SignOutRequestMessage(new Uri(config.Issuer), callbackUrl);
            signoutMessage.SetParameter("wtrealm", IdentityConfig.Realm ?? config.Realm);
            string signoutMsg = signoutMessage.WriteQueryString();

            FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.SignOut();      

            return new RedirectResult(signoutMsg);
        }
```

Comment: George, if you're still seeing this error - could you please get me a fiddler trace of the error scenario? thanks

Comment: Thank you for responding. I have since deleted the application and recreated the example and this time log out works as expected. I should have thought of adding a fiddler trace file for this. Next time I encounter a similar issue I'll be sure to capture the trace.

Comment: @gmasselli please help me, I have run into the same problem (vs2013, azure web app, azure active directory, same error message). I've deleted and recreated a dozen times now, nothing works! Please help me :)

Answer (score 1):

After deleting the website in Azure and the associated live.com registration for Microsoft OAuth (https://account.live.com/developers/applications/) I recreated the example and logout worked as expected. I'm pretty confident I had incorrectly registered the application with an invalid "Redirect Url" (http vs https).